# Dynamic Programming - avoiding Markov Chain's curse of dimensionality

Tags: matrix, dynamic-programming

Dynamic Programming is cursed with the massive size of one-step transition probabilities' (Markov Chains) and state-system's size as the number of states increases - requires massive amounts of RAM to store such matrices. My question is if one can find an alternative way, even if more computationally more intensive, to solve the same problem without using so much memory? Consider the following:

- To fill the Transition Probability Matrix one needs to define a set of rules, which can be incorporated into a Transition Function.
- If the Transition Function is used to obtain the transition probability on each loop (instead of computing all the values once and storing them in a Matrix), then one avoids storing the Matrix, at the expense of longer running times.
- If memoization is used (just noticed perhaps this isn't the correct term), that is, if instead of storing every single state (which in my case, is a combination of 4 state variables making it immensely big), then on each loop one uses the Transition Function to compute V (the expectation of V), and compares this value with the one previously found, if its cost function is smaller, store this value and policy. This way the state-space Matrix wouldn't have to be stored again, at the expense of longer running times.

Does this make sense for those who are proficient in Dynamic Programming (Bellman's Equation) ? I apologize if it makes no sense, I am touching Bellman's Dynamic Programming algorithms for the first time.

If someone has found evidence on how to avoid the curse of dimensionality using nested loops or any other form, do share.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that particular topic, but with numerics of differential equations. There you also have the problem that system matrices typically are way too large to store in memory (imagine solving a system on a 1000000x1000000x1000000 grid in 3D) even though they are sparse. To solve the problem, you don't actually create the matrix but compute the needed values on the fly. Maybe you can do something similar here.

Comment: That sounds like what I'm suggesting. Do you have any paper/book which suggests such method?
PS- Why downvoting if we are saying the same? lol

Comment: I didn't downvote that (in fact I can't since I don't have the necessary reputation yet). I don't know for sure which book contains such a method, but I'll check the standard ones.

Comment: Ok the books I have here only mention that one should do it matrix-free but don't really outline how you generally go about that. Maybe the references in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix-free_methods) can help you.

Comment: Thank you Corristo. Can you mention the books where it states that you can do it matrix-free?